# Modular automorphism group associated with a normal state on a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two normal states on a von Neumann algebra $M$. Denote $\sigma_t^{\tau_i}(i=1, 2)$ by the modular automorphism group associated with $\tau_i$. If $\sigma_t^{\tau_1}(x)=\sigma_t^{\tau_2}(x)$ for any $x\in M$, can we conclude that $\tau_1=\tau_2$?

What about the case when $M$ is a factor?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is finite but it is not a factor, you can construct two different traces. As the modular group of a trace is trivial, you get two distinct normal states with the same modular group.

If I remember correctly, the condition $\sigma^\varphi_t=\sigma^\psi_t$ is equivalent to the existence of invertible positive $h\eta  M_\psi\cap M_\varphi$ with $\psi=h\,\varphi$. What I don't remember is whether the centralizer can be non-trivial in a factor.

Comment: Anywhere where Tomita Theory is developed. The modular group is trivial on the centralizer (actually, the centralizer consists precisely of those elements left invariant by the modular group). For a trace, the centralizer is everything.

Comment: I don't understand the last statement. Would you mind explaining it in details?

Comment: Theorem 2.6.$\ $

Comment: I mean how to prove the following concluaion:the condition       $\sigma^\varphi_t=\sigma^\psi_t$  is  equivalent to the existence of invertible positive h∈Mψ∩Mφ with $\psi=h\,\varphi$

Comment: Corollary 3.6. $\ $

Comment: A non-faithful weight? What do you know exactly about modular theory for a non-faithful weight? Takesaki does it only for faithful weights, so I wouldn't know what survives. And I'm not sure where you get that $\psi=\psi\circ \sigma_t^\varphi$ occurs only on  $M_\psi$; that's not what Corollary 3.6 says.

Comment: I don't really know what is true when the weight is not faithful. Takesaki only does modular theory for faithful weights; he doesn't even define the modular operator for non-faithful weights. As for the rest, I have no idea why you insist with $M_\psi$. You always have $\psi=\psi\circ\sigma_t^\psi$ **everywhere**, so you get $\psi=\psi\circ\sigma_t^\varphi$ everywhere.

Comment: Let me only add that modular theory for non-faithful weights is briefly discussed by Takesaki in the second volume starting on page 127. There is also something [here](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/2833), [here](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/2877), and [here](https://math.bme.hu/~petz/pdf/26quasi.pdf).

Comment: Nice, thanks! $ $